# Domain Driven design and representing process state

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, finite-state-machine

I'm trying to find a good way to implement state transitions for a job posting. This is just an experiment in trying to write better code.
[You can find the code and a diagram in this repo.](https://github.com/RaicuRobert/DDD-State-Transitions)

The main problem I have is how can I write the code in such a way that there are as few as possible exceptions thrown. For example, I'm not a big fan of [this implementation](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/state) as there are state transitions in the LockedState that have no purpose. Others throw exceptions where a transition is not possible and in my eyes, it makes the code messier as you need to handle those possibly bad transitions.

The current implementation I have is not perfect either as interface methods in C# don't have access to private fields. In some cases, this could be an issue. It also makes me create more or less redundant interfaces for the job offer and entity. An alternative would be to duplicate the code for transitioning to the Retracted and Failed states.

The simplest implementation I can think of is a simple entity with a state enum but modeling transitions would not be as clean.

How would you do it and why?

Comment: *"interface methods in C# don't have access to private fields"* — can you clarify this? A public method defined on an interface has the same level of access to private state as any other method.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm talking about this feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods

The interface implementing the default method does not have the context of the class.

I used this feature in a try to reduce the duplication of methods transitioning to retracted or failed states.

Comment: *"The simplest implementation I can think of is a simple entity with a state enum but modeling transitions would not be as clean."* - would you mind to tell us how this looks like precisely (especially your enum)? For me, this sounds pretty clean, especially **because** you said it is the most simple implementation you can think of. Any kind of state machine sounds like heavily overengineered.

Comment: Well, the enum would have the values as the current state names. As for transitioning, there could be one method for each transition with the necessary validation checks to see if the transition is possible or not. I could extract the state validation into a few specification classes to keep the offer class small. 

The reason why I'm not a big fan of this approach is that the transitions are not that obvious from the signature of the constructor and methods. It requires you to either extensively document them or inspect the code

Answer (score 1):

I would have an anaemic model approach with the possible actions in their own classes implementing :

```
public interface IAction
{
    bool IsValidFor(JobOffer j)
    void Apply(JobOffer j)
}
```

Apply will throw exceptions if you send an invalid `JobOffer`, ie not in a state where the action should take place, but you avoid this happening in less than exceptional circumstances by first evaluating `IsValidFor` to give you a list of possible actions.

I favour this approach because `JobOffer` matches what you mean when you talk about it and is divorced from possible actions. It's a collection of data that has a state. its not a `PendingJobOffer` or a `CompletedJobOffer` or whatever containing the logic for multiple possible actions.

Additionally the actions are separated from each other. You can make up new actions or change existing ones without worrying about encoding your flow into them. For example if `CompleteJobOffer()` currently comes from state "OnGoing" but changes so that the job offer needs to be "AcceptedByBothParties" I just change `CompletionAction`. I don't have to go edit `OnGoingJobOffer.Complete()` and move it to some new `AcceptedByBothPartiesJobOffer.Complete()`

Further-more, it deals with change over time well. If I have a bunch of JobOffers in state Rejected from ages ago, but then I change the process, I don't have make a `RejectedJobOffer` class which is generic enough to deal with both the old rejected offers *and* the current process. Or make a `RejectedJobOffer` and a `RejectedLegacyJobOffer`. I just change the Actions to reflect the business logic `if offer.date < whatever then throw/return false`